# Calendar subscription with nativescript

Tags: calendar, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

So I'm familiar with the Calendar plugin with that allows apps to access the native calendar app (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-calendar).
I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to programmatically add a subscription to a calendar api using nativescript?

If this feature isn't available on android yet, is there a way I can modify the source code for the ios project?

This is the EventKit code in a regular ios project.

```
NSString *url = @"http://server/filename.ics";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Can I still do this with a nativescript app?

Comment: What do you mean by "subscription to a calendar api" .. if you want simply to populate your calendar with data - yes this is possible with ```createEvent``` .. the second part of the question is also unclear... share a code base and better explanation of what you are trying to achive and what you ahve tried so far